# How to set a custom name from own raspberry webserver?

Tags: linux, webserver, raspberry-pi

Hello I'm a newbie in the raspberry world so I need a bit help to achieve my target. 
I successfully installed a webserver (lamp) on my raspberry pi.

Now if I type the ip address of raspberry ip into my computer (windows 10), something like this: 192.168.1.7 I can see the page **"It work!"** So all is setted successfully.

What I want achieve now is set a custom name for access to my webserver.

In particular now for access to my php project I must type in the windows browser this url: 192.168.1.7/projects/php_project_name

I want simply access with a custom name, instead of the ip, like:

webserver/projects/php_project_name

how can I achieve this? thanks.

Comment: you can add webserver to the windows 10 hosts file to make the named resource available from that computer.  Making a named resource available on a local network is trickier because not all systems advertise names and look for the named resource the same way.  Making the page available from the internet means you need a domain name, likely a dynamic DNS provider, and a port forwarding rule on your router.

Comment: could you please show me how can I do this in w10? thanks

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: @Tyson thanks now seems to working very nice. But isn't possible do this in the raspberry, so windows recognize "webserver" directly? thanks again have good day

Comment: You would need to get your server advertised in DNS.  Your router may already do that using a different name.  If not you could add a light-wieght DNS proxy to your network and configure your router to use it.